# dnf: missing library, but does exist

Tags: redhat, rpm, dependencies, libraries, dnf

Trying to install `libmediainfo` with **`dnf`**, got an error about **missing library** that **does exist**.

How to solve this ?

Here is `dnf`output:

```
$ sudo dnf install -v libmediainfo --allowerasing
DNF version: 4.7.0
cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
User-Agent: constructed: 'libdnf (Rocky Linux 8.6; generic; Linux.x86_64)'
repo: using cache for: appstream
repo: using cache for: baseos
repo: using cache for: extras
repo: using cache for: epel
repo: using cache for: epel-modular
--> Starting dependency resolution
--> Finished dependency resolution
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libtinyxml2.so.6()(64bit)
      needed by libmediainfo-22.03-1.el8.x86_64
```

The missing library is installed on the system:

```
$ ll /usr/lib64/libtiny*
    21 Aug 16  2019 libtinyxml.so -> libtinyxml.so.0.2.6.2
    21 Aug 16  2019 libtinyxml.so.0 -> libtinyxml.so.0.2.6.2
119272 Aug 16  2019 libtinyxml.so.0.2.6.2
    20 May 23  2014 libtinyxml2.so.2 -> libtinyxml2.so.2.1.0
 84816 May 23  2014 libtinyxml2.so.2.1.0
    20 Jun 28 11:22 libtinyxml2.so.6 -> libtinyxml2.so.2.1.0
```

### Additional info

The `libtinyxml2.so` was installed by hand (libtinyxml**2** not found by `dnf`) with

```
wget https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/t/tinyxml2-2.1.0-2.20140406git6ee53e7.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh tinyxml2-2.1.0-2.20140406git6ee53e7.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo ldconfig
```

### Important

`ldconfig` doesn't see the libtinyxml2.so.**6** . Could be a clue for a solution.

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep tinyx
    libtinyxml2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libtinyxml2.so.2
    libtinyxml.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libtinyxml.so.0
    libtinyxml.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libtinyxml.so
```

Comment: Try to remove then install the library with command `dnf localinstall tinyxml2-2.1.0-2.20140406git6ee53e7.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks, but dnf says `Package tinyxml2-2.1.0-xxxxx.el7.x86_64 is already installed.` and doesn't reinstall.

Comment: First remove the package, then install it

Comment: @RomeoNinov Worked, thank you. But dnf still complaining when installing libmediainfo. Edited the question to add an important detail.